# Angular V5 with django rest framework, CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django-rest-framework, angular5

I am using Angular V5 and Django rest framework to create application.
but when I am trying to login on application using post method I am getting 
**"CSRF verification failed. Request aborted".**

**Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.**

My code snippets are as below :

1- in auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  login(user): Promise<any> {
    let url: string = `/users`;
    return this.http.post(url, user, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();
  }
}
```

2- in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

// third party imports
// import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoututingModule } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/layout/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/layout/footer/footer.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/layout/navigation/navigation.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './components/users/users.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

import  { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // ngx-bootstrap
    // BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),

    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoututingModule
  ],
  providers: [UsersService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: is your client application separated from your backing service? Or are both served together in a single application (_i.e_ Django renders the Angular 5 client)?

Comment: Hi Sule, thanks for your update, 

"Yes"  my client application is separate from backed service.

Root Folder having two separate folder 1) client and 2) backed

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rest_framework.views.APIView`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.7.3/rest_framework/views.py#L140) or subclasses of it which exempts requests from having to be processed through `CsrfMiddleware`.

`csrf_exempt` decorator in `django.views.decorators.csrf` module may also be applied to your Django view function bound to the `/users` route to keep requests from being processed through `CsrfMiddleware`.

Any of the above approaches are fitting for your system since there is a separation between the API service and frontend client.

Also, I have assumed that you're not using session-based authentication.

If using session-based authentication, register a route and bind this to a view function that returns a csrf token in the response headers. You could return a `204 No Content` response.

In this view function make a token using `get_token` function in [`django.middleware.csrf`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/middleware/csrf.py#L80) module.

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class TokenAPIView(APIView):
   def get(self, request):
       csrftoken = get_token(request)
       return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
            headers={'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
       )
```

Grab this token from response headers and cookie it. Whenever any non-idempotent kind of HTTP request is made with Angular 5 client make sure to pass this token in request headers.